# How to access https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me through OAuth 2.0 in Java?

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am supporting a website that integrates with Twitter through Twitter Oauth v1.1. It supports "Sign up with Twitter" and "Sign in with Twitter", which allow a user to sign up/in on our website with their Twitter credenials.

I need to upgrade it to Twitter OAuth 2.0. My understanding is that instead of getting user information at this 1.1 endpoint

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true
```

I need to use this v2 endpoint

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me
```

Here is the section of code that accesses this endpoint. Before this section  is reached, the program was able to get an authorization code from Twitter, and then it was able to use the authorization code, a code verifier, and other other parameters to get access_token_from_Twitter.

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me");
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(builder.build());
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token_from_Twitter);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
```

The response status is 403, which shows something is wrong. What is the correct way of using this v2 endpoint?

Comment: not sure if it helps but try add header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: I tried it. It is still not working. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: There are two possible scenarios then: your app in twitter is suspended/not working or access_token expired. You should request `2/users/me` asap as you get token

Comment: Third scenario you are not using right link to get code. In API v2 link to get code is `https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={$clientId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUrl}&scope=tweet.read%20users.read&state=state&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain`

Comment: @jsHate, thanks so much for your attention and help! My program is able to redirect users to Twitter, get authorization, obtain access code. The error happens when the program tries to obtain user information. I looked my Twitter dev account. It is a free account, good status, and should be able to get "25 requests / 24 hours"